# how is scalaz.Equal resolved

Tags: scala, implicit, scalaz

There is `Equal` object in `scalaz` package:

```
package scalaz

object Equal extends EqualLow {

  // ...

  implicit def Tuple3Equal[A: Equal, B: Equal, C: Equal]: Equal[(A, B, C)] = equal {
    case ((a1, b1, c1), (a2, b2, c2)) => a1 ≟ a2 && b1 ≟ b2 && c1 ≟ c2
  }

  //...
}
```

How it is possible that compiler knows, that `implicit def Tuple3Equal` method will be called when I call:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

implicitly[Equal[Tuple3[Int,Int,Int]]]
//or
(1,2,3).=== (1,2,3)
```

Note that, I am importing only `scalaz._` package and `Scalaz._` object and there is no explicit import scalaz.Equal._ which contains implicits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when looking for implicits of type `Foo`, companion object of `Foo` is always checked. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5598107/9204) for a complete description of the implicit resolution.